# How to destroy/remove class completely out of system so any loop run by it is stopped

Tags: python, loops, class

Hey guys I have a problem with deleting class instances.  I have a class which whenever an instance is created, it starts a while loop. But when I try to delete that instance the loop still runs no matter what. How can I delete it properly so no sign of that instance left?
could you help me please?

I have already tried to make an instace, then append ist to a list, then delete it from that list but it didn't work.

```
class Foo:
  delf __init__(self):
    self.x = 0
    while True:
      self.x += 1
  def die(self):
    instances.remove(self)

instances = []
foo = Foo()
instances.append(foo)
foo.die()
```

Comment: There's an infinite loop in `__init__`, how do you expect your code to go further than this?

Comment: There's no way the code above would even *reach* `instances.append(foo)`; `Foo()` never returns.

Comment: Is this a threaded process that you wish to kill?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have a `while True` loop in the constructor, the constructor will never exit and `instances.append(foo)` will be unreachable. Assuming you put `while True` by mistake, you can use del https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 0

foo = Foo()
print(foo.x)
#0
del foo #this deletes the object
print(foo)
#NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```